# KQL Summarize unable to show Null values

Tags: kql

I've stripped some of my query out but I am trying to count the entries from my query from 5 minute buckets.

There may occasionally be no data in these buckets as there were no requests but I want to be able to represent that as a 0 rather than null so that I can then compare that against a previous week.

`requests | where success == true | summarize Count = count() by bin(timestamp, 5m) | extend Count = iif(isnull(Count) or Count == 0, 0, Count)`

This is returning the following [results set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Niyms.png)

because of my `| extend Count = iif(isnull(Count) or Count == 0, 0, Count)` I would have expected my results to show all the 5 min buckets between 09:05 and 09:30 but with a count of 0

I can get this to a 0 with a make series but I'm not wanting to make  series for graphing as I want to then use this data set to compare to say the week prior to work out any differences

Answer (score 0):

> KQL Summarize unable to show Null values

To show `NULL` values instead of **0**. You can use below query, `unmatched_data` filters out `timestamps` from the generated sequence to simulate unmatched data. In that `timestamps` matching the ones in the `real_data` table are excluded from the sequence. The `Count` for these unmatched timestamps is initialized to **0**. `left outer` join is used to to ensure all timestamps from the sequence are included, irrespective of the existence of equivalent data in the `real_data`. `final_data` checks if the `Count` is null or zero and replaces it with **0** accordingly.

```sql
let start = datetime(2024-03-18T09:05:00);
let end = datetime(2024-03-18T09:30:00);
let step = 5m;

let real_data = datatable(timestamp: datetime, Count: int)
[
    datetime(2024-03-18T09:10:00), 5,
    datetime(2024-03-18T09:20:00), 3
];

let sequence = range x from start to end step step | extend timestamp = x;

let unmatched_data = sequence
| where timestamp != datetime(2024-03-18T09:10:00) and timestamp != datetime(2024-03-18T09:20:00)
| extend Count = 0;

let joined_data = sequence 
| join kind=leftouter real_data on timestamp;

let final_data = joined_data
| extend Count = iif(isnull(Count) or Count == 0, 0, Count);

final_data
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Hey Balaji, Please excuse me, I'm not following this, pleaae could you expand ?